VS Code F5 Not Starting Python Program and Can't Change Python Interpreter
I’m experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code where pressing F5 to start my Python program doesn’t trigger any reaction—nothing happens. I attempted to troubleshoot by disabling all extensions, but when I do that and try to run the program, I encounter an error.
Additionally, I'm unable to change the Python interpreter in VS Code. I have both Anaconda and Python 3.12.5 installed on my system, but VS Code only recognizes the Anaconda environment. Other GUIs can detect both environments, so I’m not sure why VS Code is having this problem.

Reinstalled VS Code

Disabled Python extensions

Freshly installed Anaconda and Python

Verified that the program works in Spyder I’ve tried reinstalling the Python extension and updating VS Code, but the issue persists. Any insights on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Reinstalled VS Code

Disabled Python extensions

Freshly installed Anaconda and Python

Verified that the program works in Spyder



What are you doing to run your program? Are you runnuing module or package? Did you read VSCode python tutorial? It's a text redactor btw not a IDE, setting up interpreter is a half way. You need to set up tasks to run your program, or use terminal to run it directly.

Thank you for your response! I’m sorry if my question was unclear—I’m not working on a whole program or a large project with multiple modules. I’m just trying to run a single .py file in VS Code.

Hello, do you have the python extension, and the Python Debugger Extension installed? If use the run button in the upper right corner, will this be successful? Also, if vscode doesn't recognize the Python 3.12.5 you have installed. You can open the command panel with the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P, type select interpreter, and select Enter interpreter path. It is also to note that the installed python environment needs to be added to the environment variables. You can check add python.exe to PATH when installing python.

Hello, yes, all extensions are installed. Using the run button also has no effect. I tried adding the interpreter as you suggested, but only Anaconda is visible, not the regular Python installation. Providing the interpreter path doesn’t work either. I added python.exe to PATH and confirmed it in Environment Variables.
After starting the file (either with F5 or the Run button), nothing happens, but the run icon with the bug (debugger) appears on the bottom bar with the title: "Python Debugger: Python File (ML training)." (ML training is the folder where the file is located).

This could be a different manifestation of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/78886126/7483211

Can you try setting the following in your user settings? "python.locator": "js",?

@CorneliusRoemer, thank you that sorted the problem! Now VS Code sees all installed interpreters and let me choose which to use; ah, and most importantly Python files execute now. Thank you again !

I've added it as an answer, I'm glad it helped! This is a bug in vscode you encountered - not your fault!

OP confirmed that the following addition to user settings fixed it for them:
"python.locator": "js",

So this question is essentially equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78886126/7483211 (though that is not obvious at first). It's a bug in VS Code.
